# Are there any vegan gummy sweets in brick and mortar shops in the UK?

Tags: veganism, substitutes, uk, shopping

I would like to know whether there are some vegan gummy sweets (like Haribo gummy bears and such) available in traditional, brick and mortar shops in the UK.

I have searched on the internet but I have either found just online shops offering these, or vegetarian gummy sweets or one type of vegan gummy sweets with Coca-Cola flavour which is not really my thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marks and Spencer seem to have a few options, I found a list [here](https://health.marksandspencer.com/uploads/pdfs/Vegans.pdf) of their vegan foods (confectionery starts on page 4), this link is dated 10th Feb 2017, but includes an email contact to get an up-to-date list.

I've only tried the Mocktail Jellies, which are quite a bit softer than a Haribo type sweet, but some of the other sweets on the list seem like they might be closer to what you're after.

Comment: M&S have a new list updated November found linked on this page:  https://www.marksandspencer.com/s/food-to-order/health/vegan-planted-based (I use the page rather than the direct link because it's a terrible URL for the document directly).  I'm pleased to report M&S Jelly Fruits appear to be vegan now.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the German brand [Haribo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haribo) is available in the UK, they (and probably others) make a kind of vegan gummy.

While they sell dozens of different shapes, this kind is called "gummi pasta" and doesn't use gelatin.

[image: Haribo Pasta-Frutta]

You might find that other similar "hard gummies" are vegan.

Answer (score 2):

Jelly tots are vegan. [Here is an official source](http://www.nestle.co.uk/asset-library/documents/nutritionhealthwellness/vegan%20list.pdf), it's a list of vegan products by Nestlé.